# Sqrt of polynomial, How to find integer X that gives integer y

Tags: calculus, number-theory

I am trying to solve how to find an integer X that gives an integer result of Y on an equation that has the square root of a polynomial.  The equations are of the type:

$$y =\sqrt{ax^2+bx+c}$$

where x>0 and y>=0.
as a more concrete example:

$$y= \sqrt{x^2 + 10036x - 10015}$$

While if I manually step x I get y=2369 at x=532, I'm trying to find a numerical way to solve these without having to step.

How can I solve these equations to quickly find the (first) integer x and y pair?  Thank you.

Comment: Hint: Square both sides and complete the square (in $x $).  You will get a difference of two squares equal to a constant, and one can then find any integer solutions by factoring that constant in various ways.

Comment: https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/completing-square.html

Comment: ... And whether $a$ is a square or not will make this question very different.

Comment: $(p_r,q_r)$ is smallest solution. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PellEquation.html

Comment: Thanks all, appreciated.   Btw -  Is there... anyone who can show the working of 'completing the squares' for the example I gave and illustrate how y and x would then be found?  I'm having some...newbie problems getting my head around it.

Comment: @quizitor I've given an answer showing, with quite a few details, how to use "completing the squares" and illustrating how to determine the $x$ and $y$ values with your particular example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you requested, here is the squaring and showing how to solve for your specific example, with quite a few steps included to make it easier for you to follow along:

\begin{align}
y & = \sqrt{x^2 + 10036x - 10015} \\
y^2 & = x^2 + 10036x - 10015 \\
y^2 & = x^2 + (2 \times 5018)x + 5018^2 - 5018^2 - 10015 \\
y^2 & = (x + 5018)^2 - 5018^2 - 10015 \\
y^2 - (x + 5018)^2 & = -25190339 \\
(x + 5018)^2 - y^2 & = 25190339 \\
(x + 5018 - y)(x + 5018 + y) & = 3181 \times 7919 \tag{1}\label{eq1}
\end{align}

Note I used WolframAlpha's [Online Factoring Calculator](https://www.wolframalpha.com/calculators/factoring-calculator/), double-checked the numbers multiply to the original, and confirmed they are prime in [The First 10,000 Primes](https://primes.utm.edu/lists/small/10000.txt).

If you want to just get any solution, you can have the $2$ factors on the left be any combination of the $2$ factors on the right, keeping in mind in general that the parity must be the same as the difference between the $2$ factors on the left is $2y$, although it's not an issue in this case. For each case, you will get $2$ equations in $2$ unknowns which you can relatively easily solve.

For example, you can have

$$x + 5018 - y = 3181 \tag{2}\label{eq2}$$
$$x + 5018 + y = 7919 \tag{3}\label{eq3}$$

Next, \eqref{eq3} minus \eqref{eq2} gives $2y = 4738 \implies y = 2369$. Thus, from \eqref{eq3}, you then get $x = 7919 - 2369 - 5018 = 532$. This gives one possible solution of $(532,2369)$, which is the same as the one you already found. To get the other ones, if any, you just solve for the other possible combinations of the factors, but if you're only concerned about positive values for $x$ and $y$, you don't need to worry about checking the negative factors (e.g., $-3181$ and $-7919$).

In particular, if you let $F_1 = x + 5018 - y$ and $F_2 = x + 5018 + y$, the remaining cases are $F_1 = 1, F_2 = 25190339$; $F_1 = 25190339, F_2 = 1$; and $F_1 = 7919, F_2 = 3181$. I trust you can finish the rest yourself if you so desire.