# Number theory: natural sqrt of 2nd degree polynomial above the naturals.

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, square-numbers

I am trying to find solutions to $y =\sqrt{ax^2+bx+c}, x \land y \in \mathbb{N}$.

I've looked at [Sqrt of polynomial, How to find integer X that gives integer y](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3308782/sqrt-of-polynomial-how-to-find-integer-x-that-gives-integer-y)

but the solution there assumes $a=1$, and fails when $\sqrt{a} \notin \mathbb{N}$

because $(y+\sqrt{a}x+\frac{b^2}{a})(y-\sqrt{a}x-\frac{b^2}{a})=\frac{b^2}{a}+c$ doesn't imply that the factors in LHS equal factors of RHS.

assuming i want the first $k$ solutions, methods of reducing the number numbers to check are also welcome!

I'm thinking that maybe there is some modulus you can take, that will simplify a lot. maybe with some Legendre symbol analysis thrown in. but maybe its just because i learnt these things recently XD

Comment: what do we know about $y$ ? about congruence and equals.

Comment: Are $a,b,c$ supposed to be any fixed integers, possibly also with $a \neq 0$?

Comment: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1049910___4
https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1048216__

Comment: we know nothing about $y$, and yes $a,b,c$ are fixed integers, $a \ne 0$ anyhow, individ's comment is really useful! I'm not yet certain if it covers all of the options, but Pells equation is definitely a thing I'm going to study now :)

Answer (score 1):

solved by individ in the comments!

using pells equation to solve:
https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1048216__

solving pells equation:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_xGWbZte1Ds